# What is the time complexity of BitArray initilized to 0?

Tags: c#, constructor, bitarray, code-complexity

when creating a BitArray and initializing all of its value to 0 (via constructor, `new BitArray(size, false);`) what is the time complexity of such operation? [It's not in the docs about collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/).
From reading other resources allocation in general seems to be non deterministic, but what about allocation with initial value of 0? is it guaranteed to be O(n)?

Comment: From the [BitArray Constructors MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray.-ctor#System_Collections_BitArray__ctor_System_Int32_System_Boolean_) : *This constructor is an O(n) operation, where n is length.* But if size is 0, the complixity is 0, isn't it ? "Nothing" is done, manner of speaking : [Source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/bitarray.cs,fae855547216a834,references)

Comment: @OlivierRogier you didn't understand what I was trying to say.
not that the size is 0, but that the initial value of all the bits is 0 (a.k.a the ```false``` in ```new BitArray(size, false);```)

Comment: @AvivVetaro [from the source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Collections/System/Collections/BitArray.cs,42) in that case you're paying the cost of an array allocation, and of the CLR zeroing it. That's going to be technically O(n), but in practice it will be close to O(1) for the array sizes you're actually going to be creating

Comment: @AvivVetaro Ok I understand. In the future, say `false` for boolean, please, else `0` is de facto for `size`... So Why would it be different for false or true? `m_array[i] = fillValue;`

Comment: @OlivierRogier It might be different because, if you're passing `true`, it needs go loop through the array and set each element to non-zero, but it doesn't if you pass `false`

Comment: @ canton7 No, the [code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/bitarray.cs,fae855547216a834,references) does not check for false to ignore the loop. The loop applies the initialization of the memory blocks, otherwise we will get azard values from the stack, for example. Even false the memoryt blocks must be set to 0.

Comment: If you have cause to worry about whether creating these arrays is a significant operation in your code, you should be profiling in any case, because things like garbage collection tend to dwarf whatever constructors are doing -- and that is assuming you've correctly identified the code doing the allocating as a bottleneck in the first place. Initialization costs are probably the least of your worries.

Comment: @OlivierRogier Please see the link I posted in a comment above. The .NET Core version of the code **does** check that. Also read the latter part of that comment where I explain that the CLR does have to zero the memory in both cases

Comment: @canton7 Ok, thanks. Does it means that Core auto-fill with 0 every new arrays, and on resizing, even in the stack ? So in case of using true, the array is initialized with 0, then with -1 ?

Comment: @OlivierRogier Heap-allocated objects are always zero'd (and arrays are always heap-allocated, barring `stackalloc` and fixed size buffers). Locals are always zero'd unless the flag `skiplocalsinit` is specified, which you can do on newer .NET Core versions using an attribute. So yes, in the case of passing `true`, the array is inited twice

Comment: @canton7 Ok, thanks. So .NET Framework and Core is even more different from my memory in x86 assembler and C than I saw...

Comment: @AvivVetaro Can you add to the question tags, or in the body if several (to know each cases), what is the platform relevant to the question, please ? Is it for .NET Framework, .NET Core, .NET Standard, .NET 5...

Comment: @canton7 A large array allocation would take entire fresh virtual memory pages. These will be virtually zeroed by the kernel, and as soon as they are read or written first time they are mapped to real memory, and zeroed first **if** they have already been used. I believe it's a pretty fast operation. A fresh real memory page is going to be zero already.

Comment: @Charlieface This is .NET: the memory is most likely coming from a segment already managed by the GC, particularly for a small allocation like this. So that memory will have been previously used for a different object, most likely, and needs to be zero'd by the runtime

Comment: @Charlieface: and all of that would *still* be O(n) in the worst case, albeit with amortized costs. This is another reason why the time complexity would not be very useful in practice, though -- beyond the simple observation that bigger collections will probably increase the running time, the practical effects require profiling.

Comment: @canton7 That would depend on whether it's going into the LOH or if the small heap has not been that large yet. To be honest, I assumed we're talking about the LOH and a massive BitArray say hundreds of MB, otherwise the whole thing is a joke anyway.

Comment: @Charlieface Yeah, my assumption was that noone's going to make a bitarray with over half a million elements, hence the stuff I said about it all effectively being O(1) to the number of elements anyway, and Jeroen's stuff about it being dominated by other factors